# Series, conditional or absolute? +more

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is for a presentation, so I not just want to solve it, but also be able to talk a bit about it

$$\sum \limits_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{n-1}{n^2}$$

1)Show that the series converges, is it absolute or conditional?

First off we quickly see that the series is alternating and if w use the alternating series test:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{n-1}{n^2})=\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2})=0$$

And see that the series converges. But to determine weather it's absolute or conditional, we compare it to the harmonic series

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{n-1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{n-1}{n}=\lim_{x \to \infty}1-\frac{1}{n}=1$$

Since this is different from what we found in our earlier test, the series is conditional convergent.

2)What can you tell about $|S_9-S|$?.

This is where it gets a bit unclear to me, what can I tell about this? I calculated that $S_9=\frac{8}{81}$ but I dont know what to do with it.

All in all: Is there anything Im missing on the first part and what am I supposed to possibly tell about the other?

Comment: What is that "alternating series test" you talk about? You only need to check the absolute value of the series' general term sequence converges to zero **monotonically** , and I don't think you did this.

Comment: Might have been lost in transelation; we are not using english written books, so it's sometimes a bit hard to transelate certain mathematical rules properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are being asked to use [Leibnitz' estimate](http://planetmath.org/leibnizestimateforalternatingseries)  for alternating series.  That is, if you have a series that passes the alternating series test, the error in every partial sum is at most the very next term of the series.  That is, $$|S_9-S|\le \frac{10-1}{10^2}=0.09$$

Comment: You mean $a_{10}$, not $S_{10}$.

Comment: Thanks for the sharp eyes, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

First, to use the alternating series test, you also need to show that $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence (assuming you are working with $\sum (-1)^{n+1}a_n$).

Second, the alternating series test also includes the statement that $|S-S_n| \le a_{n+1}$.